# Define different login pages web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, umbraco7, authorize

I am using Umbraco 7

I have 2 different type of members: let's say `MemberTypeOne` and `MemberTypeTwo`.

In `web.config` I have defined default login page in case a view is marked `[MemberAuthorize]`

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="yourAuthCookie" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" />
    </authentication>
```

I want to define two different login pages for each member type eg. for `MemberTypeOne` would be `/login-member-one.aspx`, for `MemberTypeTwo` would be `/login-member-two.aspx` in case the relevant user is not authenticated.

Can I and how to achieve it? Thanks

Comment: Why can't both member types ('Roles') login through the same form?

Comment: Because the content for them is different and one is using main site while the other one is using a microsite within umbraco.

Comment: You know the member type **after** the user has logged in. How will you know it **before** to present the right login page?

Comment: Because the login pages are two different pages?? I don't think it should be a worry right now

Answer (score 0):

Define all your content - for both member types - within the `login.aspx` page, but within different panels - let's say `PanelOne` for `MemberTypeOne` and `PanelTwo` for `MemberTypeTwo`.

Next, during the `Page_Load` event in your code behind file, determine the type of the member and set the visibility of the two panels accordingly. I.e. if the member is of type `MemberTypeOne` set `Panel1.Visible = True` and `Panel2.Visible = False`

Do note that setting a server side control `Visible` property causes it not to be written to the response at all.

In case you want to distinguish the member types based on the path, you can just provide different query strings for your login page. E.g.

`MemberTypeOne` login link could be `/login.aspx?membertype=1`

`MemberTypeTwo` login link could be `/login.aspx?membertype=2`

## UPDATE

Since your layout requires a different master page to be loaded, you need to redirect the response to another page, causing the whole page lifecycle to start over. I mean, you can use your `login.aspx` just as a starting point for the login process. During the `Page_Load`, check the member type and do a `Server.Transfer` to the appropriate page.

Comment: Thanks but I can't. They using different masters, different layout, different anything. One login page is not an option

Comment: Are the protected pages for both member types located under different folders/namespaces? If so, you can define different `web.config` files in each of the folders, containing protected resources...

Comment: I have no means to check what was the member type after I redirect to web.config's login page